# Don't return model if it is null

Tags: kotlin, graphql

I want to return a GraphQl response to UI, where I have to enable or disable a particular feature based on the response.

I am getting a response in both the cases, i.e if value found then a proper string is getting rendered and is sent back a response, but when value is not found then null is getting sent as a response from the kotlin data model.

```
data class FinalObject(
     val isEnableDisable : String? = null
)
```

Kotlin class for GraphQl

```
@GraphQLDescription("Random string")
data class ActualClassForGraphQl(
     val finalObject: FinalObject
)
```

Kotlin class where actual logic is written

```
@Component
class ActualClassForLogic{
      fun isEnableDisable():FinalObject{
           if(true){
              return FinalObject("some string")
           }
           return FinalObject()
      }
}
```

Expected result:

Nothing needs to be sent, i.e the key FinalObject itself need not to get populated in response, i.e an empty response body needs to sent to UI.

Actual result :
In case when it is entering in "if" block i.e success scenario

```
FinalObject{
     isEnableDisable:"some string"
}
```

In case when it is not entering "if" block i.e failure scenario

```
FinalObject{
     isEnableDisable:null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unless i misunderstood your question, I think thats not how GraphQL spec is defined, its more driven from client side than server side what to display in response and what not, If client sends that field(finalObject ?) in query, it should be returned regardless of what value(null on non null) and thats what the contract graphql spec gives to users.